# Adding a whitelist to a quit all app but list not working

Tags: list, applescript

So I am trying to make a quit all app that includes a whitelist for the apps that you don't want to quit. Though after you enter the whitelist items, I want it to say "Are you sure you want to quit all applications except " and then the items from the white list. But the items in the whitelist are conjoined and I type in finder and chrome but it says "Are you sure you want to quit all applications except finderchrome?". So I add the code below and type in finder and chrome in the whitelist.

```
set orginizedList to item 1 of white_list
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
repeat (length of white_list) times
    set i to 2
    set orginizedList to orginizedList & item i of white_list & ", "
    set i to i + 1
end repeat
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now it says "Are you sure you want to quit all applications except finder, finder, finder,?"

Here is the code:

```
    say "are you sure you want to quit all applications?"
set white_list to {""}
set doneWhitelist to ""

repeat until doneWhitelist = "Done"
    set whiteListedApps to display dialog "WhiteList" buttons {"Add More", "Done"} default answer "Finder"
    set whiteListedAppNames to text returned of whiteListedApps
    set doneWhitelist to button returned of whiteListedApps
    set white_list to white_list & whiteListedAppNames
end repeat

set orginizedList to item 1 of white_list
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
repeat (length of white_list) times
    set i to 2
    set orginizedList to orginizedList & item i of white_list & ", "
    set i to i + 1
end repeat
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
set confirmQuit to display alert "Are you sure you want to quit all applications except for " & orginizedList & "?" buttons {"Yes", "No"}
set confirmQuit to button returned of confirmQuit
if confirmQuit = "No" then
    error number -128
else
    tell application "System Events" to set the visible of every process to true

    try
        tell application "Finder"
            set process_list to the name of every application whose visible is true
        end tell
        repeat with i from 1 to (number of items in process_list)
            set this_process to item i of the process_list
            if this_process is not in white_list then
                tell application this_process
                    quit
                end tell
            end if
        end repeat
    on error
        tell the current application to display dialog "An error has occurred!" & return & "This script will now quit" buttons {"Quit"} default button 1 with icon 0
    end try
end if
```

Please help me fix the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be a solution that the OP was looking for but this is a different approach to accomplish the end goal, which is to quit multiple applications at once.

To me it seems like an awful lot of work with unnecessary code to add applications to a whitelist variable and loop through those items etc.

Why not just select items from a list of the visible application processes and pass those selected items to the quit routine?

Here is a simplified version of AppleScript code which quickly allows a user to select the applications to quit from a list without the additional dialogs and alerts (which can easily be added back to the code if need be)

```
set quitList to {}
set pidList to {}

tell application "System Events" to set visibleApps to name of every application process whose visible is true

activate
set quitList to (choose from list visibleApps with title "Choose The Apps To Kill" with prompt ¬
    "Choose The Apps To Quit Running" OK button name "OK" cancel button name "CANCEL" with multiple selections allowed)

tell application "System Events"
    repeat with i from 1 to count of quitList
        set thisItem to item i of quitList
        tell application process thisItem
            set thePID to unix id
            set end of pidList to thePID
        end tell
    end repeat
end tell

repeat with i in pidList
    do shell script "kill " & i
end repeat
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**  Taking it one step further, this following code allows to choose from visible application or invisible application processes to kill.

```
use AppleScript version "2.5" -- runs on 10.11 (El Capitan) and later
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

global appsToKill
property NSArray : a reference to current application's NSArray

activate
set theChoice to button returned of (display dialog ¬
    "WOULD YOU LIKE TO LIST VISIBLE OR INVISIBLE APP PROCESSES?" buttons {"CANCEL", "VISIBLE", "INVISIBLE"} default button "INVISIBLE" cancel button "CANCEL" with title ¬
    "  WOULD YOU LIKE TO LIST VISIBLE OR INVISIBLE APP PROCESSES?  " with icon 2 giving up after 10)

if theChoice is "INVISIBLE" then
    listInvisibleAppProcesses(false)
else if theChoice is "VISIBLE" then
    listInvisibleAppProcesses(true)
else if theChoice is "CANCEL" then
    return
else if theChoice is "" then
    return
end if

set aList to ((NSArray's arrayWithArray:appsToKill)'s sortedArrayUsingSelector:"compare:") as list

activate
set killApp to (choose from list aList with title "Choose The App To Kill" with prompt ¬
    "Choose The App" OK button name "OK" cancel button name "CANCEL" with multiple selections allowed)

set pidList to {}

if killApp is not false then
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat with i from 1 to count of killApp
            set thisItem to item i of killApp
            tell application process thisItem
                set thePID to unix id
                set end of pidList to thePID
            end tell
        end repeat
    end tell
else
    return
end if

repeat with i in pidList
    do shell script "kill " & i
end repeat

on listInvisibleAppProcesses(trueOrFalse)
    tell application "System Events"
        set appsToKill to name of every application process where visible is trueOrFalse
    end tell
end listInvisibleAppProcesses
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The whitelist dialog is a little confusing, and adds the default entry no matter what, so I would use a more descriptive prompt, leave the default blank, and check the result before adding:

```
repeat -- forever
  set whiteListedApp to display dialog "Add to WhiteList:" buttons {"Add Item", "Done"} default answer ""
  set whiteListedAppName to text returned of whiteListedApp
  if button returned of whiteListedApps is "Done" then exit repeat
  if (whiteListedAppName is not "") and (whiteListedAppName is not in white_list) then set white_list to white_list & whiteListedAppName
end repeat
```

To clean up the final dialog a little more, I would also add **Finder** to the initial `white_list` (since it is always in there anyway):

```
set white_list to {"Finder"}
```

then use something like:

```
set orginizedList to ""
repeat with anItem in rest of white_list
  set orginizedList to orginizedList & anItem & ", "
end repeat
if (count white_list) < 2 then -- nothing added
  set orginizedList to "Finder"
else
  set orginizedList to text 1 thru -3 of orginizedList & " and Finder"
end if
```